# Where should I put service components while using Redux?

Tags: react-native, design-patterns, redux, react-redux

In my app I got service classes like SpeechRecognizer, VoiceRecorder ...
I wonder should I put them into the state of application, my personal opinion that they don't form the state, so then where to put them.
Also to notice, SpeechRecognizer is initialized with callbacks that are called when certain event occurs, so who shall subscribe to them and how to implement that subscription ?

Comment: Use Redux-Saga with Redux. Saga has its own thread where you can implement your services. SpeechRecognizer and VoiceRecorder should be implemented at component level, these component will form the state in my opinion.

Comment: @PirShukarullahShah thanks, sounds good, now I am going through Sagas documentation and examples

Comment: Up vote if my comment helped you.